# Powershell get SQL instance

Tags: powershell

I am using the below script to get the SQL instance name and then perform some tasks related to it. I am unable to get it working can you help me figure out how to fix the issue?

```
    $SQLInstances = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances
    foreach ($sql in $SQLInstances) {
       [PSCustomObject]@{
           InstanceName = $sql
       }
   }

Write-Host "The following SQL Instances were detected on the server $env:Computername $SQLInstances" -ForegroundColor Yellow

If ($SQLInstances -ne "MSSQLSERVER")
    {Write-Host $($env:Computername)\$($SQLInstances)
$serverName =  $($env:Computername)\$($SQLInstances)}

    Else {Write-Host "Standard SQL Instance was found, proceeding with the script."
$ServerName = $env:Computername}
```

So the above code doesn't work, Write-Host displays"ComputerName(SPACE)\InstanceName" so there is an extra space there that i want to get rid off, plus  `$serverName =  $($env:Computername)\$($SQLInstances)}` throws " unexpected token / expression

How Do i fix this?

Comment: You just need to add quotes around your values. `"$($env:Computername)\$($SQLInstances)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this issue with [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7) because of how the [parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7) is interpreting tokens. `()` or `$()` (unless `()` or `$()` is part of a string) is going to be treated as one argument in expression mode. Since the default separator for `Write-Host` is a space, you get the extra space between each of your processed arguments. If you surround your entire value with double quotes, it will be parsed as a single token.

```
Write-Host "$($env:Computername)\$SQLInstances"
```

Regarding the `$serverName` assignment, it is also a parsing issue. When assigning to a variable, the parser is in expression mode. Therefore, the value must be a valid expression. The `\` character is what throws the error. Double quotes will also suffice here.

```
$serverName =  "$($env:Computername)\$SQLInstances"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Get-SqlInstance cmdlet from module sqlserver:

```
Import-Module sqlserver
If (Get-SQLInstance -ServerInstance "MSSQLSERVER"){
  # Instance found
} 
Else {
  # Instance not found
```